# Python Assigning Dictionary to a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I do not understand the results of this code:

```
o = {'x':0, 'y':0}
mylist=[]
for i in range(6):
   m = o
   m['x'] = i
   m['y'] = i*2
   mylist.append(m)
print(mylist)
```

How does `mylist` end up with 5 identical elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same dictionary for each list element.  There is only one dictionary in the code, which is assigned to `o` at the start.  Assigning it to `m` doesn't copy the dictionary.  It just creates a new reference to the same dictionary.

If you want to copy the dictionary, try this:

```
o = {'x':0, 'y':0}
mylist=[]
for i in range(6):
   m = o.copy()
   m['x'] = i
   m['y'] = i*2
   mylist.append(m)
print(mylist)
```

You can achieve the same effect by dispensing with `o` and its copies, and just creating the new dictionaries directly:

```
mylist=[]
for i in range(6):
   mylist.append({'x':i, 'y':i*2})
print(mylist)
```

You can be even more concise by using a list comprehension:

```
mylist=[{'x':i, 'y':i*2} for i in range(6)]
print(mylist)
```